# Pandas' HDFStore append dataframe memory consumption

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

I have a long running process that is retrieving data from a given source and every second saves an updated dataframe to the same file using HDFStore. The code below is the HDFWriter class whose write method is called every second with a dataframe and a timestamp.

```py
class HDFWriter(object):
  def __init__(self, source):
    self.source = source
    self.date = None
    self.hdf = self.create_hdfstore()
    self.logger = logging.getLogger(source)

  def create_hdfstore(self):
    self.date = datetime.now()
    manager = HDFFileManager(self.source, self.date)

    return HDFStore(manager.get_partial_path(), complib = 'zlib', complevel = 9)

  @staticmethod
  def get_df_name(timestamp):
    return '{:02d}/{}'.format(datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).hour, int(timestamp))

  def check_rotation(self, timestamp):
    current_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)

    if current_date.date() != self.date.date():
      if self.hdf:
        self.hdf.close()

      self.hdf = self.create_hdfstore()

  def write(self, data, timestamp):
    self.check_rotation(timestamp)
    table_name = self.get_df_name(timestamp)
    try:
      self.hdf.put(table_name, data, format = 'table', data_columns = True)
    except Exception as e:
      self.logger.error("Failed writing data")
```

The dataframes are stored under XX/123456790 where the first part is the hour of the day and the second part is the timestamp. The HDFFileManager simply manages if there is already a file with the desired name and retrieves a path that is still available, so it's inner functions can be ignored.

In a machine with limited resources, let's say about 1GB when the file grows close to that size, the process will fail due to lack of memory, triggering a fatal python exception.

Is there any known issue with HDFStore append method? This appears to be a memory leak. I've tried to isolate the memory consumption issue and I found out that if I disable the HDFWriter (the project writes to other outputs), the issue disappears.

Is there any alternative method to write Dataframes into hdf files ? I've studied using msgpack binary format to store/load dataframes from hdf files, any suggestions?